# CarrierWave + rails 4.2 + jquery file upload + progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progress-bar, carrierwave, jquery-fileupload-rails

I do not found any tutorial for Rails 4, jQuery File Upload + Progress Bar. Someone can i help me?

I need to upload a file(.xml), store it in my disc and show to the user the progress bar. How can i do it?

I'm trying do it since last week. :[